# swift 3 http request

Tags: php, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to sent input from the user to a php script to have it ultimately passed to an SQL server,  Most of the code runs but having problem with submitting the data.

```
@IBAction func submit(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let requestURL = URL(string: "*****")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:requestURL!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let song=txt1.text!
    let artist=txt2.text!
    let album=txt3.text!
    let year=txt4.text!
    let genre=txt5.text!


    let songPost = "song=" + (song as String)
    let artistPost = "&artist=" + (artist as String)
    let albumPost = "&album=" + (album as String)
    let yearPost = "&year=" + (year as String)
    let genrePost = "&genre=" +  (genre as String)

    request.httpBody = songPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = artistPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = albumPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = yearPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = genrePost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
 --->>let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            print(response)

            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

Having an issue with the urlsession.shared.datatask line of code.  Compiler error says "ambigious reference to member'dataTask(with:completionhandler:)"

What can get this code to work and how can I verify that this information was passed on the app?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get that error message is because you are passing `NSMutableURLRequest` where `URLRequest` is needed.

Changing this line:

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:requestURL!)
```

to this:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url:requestURL!)
```

should fix it.

But I recommend a little more fixes to make your request successfully sent to the server:

```
    let requestURL = URL(string: "*****")

    //You should use `URLRequest` in Swift 3, mutability is represented by `var`
    var request = URLRequest(url:requestURL!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //UITextField.text can be nil, you should treat nil cases
    //(Generally avoid using forced unwrapping `!` as far as you can.)
    let song = txt1.text ?? ""
    let artist = txt2.text ?? ""
    let album = txt3.text ?? ""
    let year = txt4.text ?? ""
    let genre = txt5.text ?? ""

    //`song`,... are all Strings, you have no need to add `as String`
    let songPost = "song=" + song
    let artistPost = "&artist=" + artist
    let albumPost = "&album=" + album
    let yearPost = "&year=" + year
    let genrePost = "&genre=" + genre

    //You need to make a single data containing all params
    //(Creating a concatenated String and getting `data` later would be another way.)
    var data = Data()
    data.append(songPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(artistPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(albumPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(yearPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(genrePost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    request.httpBody = data
    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
       ...
```

Comment: Thats awesome!! I think I was finding answers with swift 2 and mixing it in to my code, I can't tell them apart.  It doesn't show any errors and runs but when I hit submit on the app there is a Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 error, its green too instead of red, it apprears right on the line with var request = URLREQUEST.  What is a breakpoint ?

Comment: also im getting an error that says invalid redeclaration of 'viewController' which appeared out of nowhere and I don't have any functions with the same name

Comment: Good answer. You can also replace all of those `String.Encoding.utf8` references with just `.utf8`.